# How to get correct value from List<Class> in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have list as example below

```
val mylist : List<Class> = (Class(foo,1),Class(bar,2))
```

I know value `1` is coming to me but How can i get `foo` value in list?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following structure would probably work:

```
// This gets the first object of the class "Class" in your list. (First index)
Class classVariable = mylist.get(0);
// Now that you have an object of type Class, you can retrieve the value of foo // using whatever property you just used in the constructor
Type foo = classVariable.foo;
```

If you want to do it in one line:

```
VariableType foo = myList.get(0).foo
// OR
VariableType foo = myList.get(0).getFoo(); // if your class member "foo" is private access.
```

In response to the comment below this answer:

```
// NOTE: THIS CODE WILL NOT COMPILE. These are two separate snippets that
// you will have to place in the correct positions

// Class used in example:
public class Class {
    public String foo; // public so we don't have to use get() set()
    public Integer value;

    // constructor
    public Class(String foo, Integer value) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

// For loop to find the value of foo if we know a given value:
for (int i = 0; i < mylist.size(); i++) {
     // Gets an object at each index in list.
     Class object = mylist.get(i); 
     if (object.value == <INSERT VALUE THAT YOU ARE LOOKING FOR>) {
         return object.foo; // this will get the value for foo 
         // based on the other value that you know
     }
}
```

Comment: I understand and i know this but think about i have 2 or 3 value and i don’t know index of the value, so how can i get?

Comment: That means you will have to loop through the array and search for the values you want to get before retrieving them. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Yes you are right i need to expand question.. Actually i have list as in example and i know the values inside 1 and 2 but how can i get 'foo' with 'find' function or as you said loop?

Comment: It depends on what your class member is called. If it is called foo and you are also putting a variable called foo in your object constructor, then you will need to have something like for (int i = 0...) { ... if (class.foo == value) , get value of i }

Comment: Sure, I have added an example below the first example.